# R doesn't recognise my functions updates within another function

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am working on a package and currently it has a lot of functions. Inorder to load them every time I open up RStudio, I use this line of code from devtools:

```
library(devtools)
suppressMessages(load_all("~/Codes/package1/"))
```

It works fine, but the problem is whenever I change a function that has been used in another function, R doesn't recognize the changes.

For Example if I have:

```
func1 <- function() {
   print("version1")
}
func2 <- function() {
   func1()
}
```

And then change `func1` to `print("Vesion2")`, rerun it and then run func2, it would still print version1 for me.

Anyone knows whats the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devtools `load_all` function simulates loading a package. All functions from a package are stored in a package namespace. Functions remember what namespace they come from via their `environment()`.

Any code you run in the console runs in the global environment. So when you run

```
func1 <- function() {print("version2")}
```

you are creating a new function called `func1` in your global environment but the `func1` from the package namespace is still there. You've created a "shadow" function that masks the original function.

When you got to run `func2` which is still in the package namespace, it sees a call to a function named `func1`. When it goes to look for this function, it looks first in it's own namespace due to R's lexical scoping rules. It finds the original `funct1` and not the one you created in the global environment so it runs that.

Packages generally aren't meant to have their functions swapped or altered after they are loaded. You would save to save the source and call `load_all` to reload that folder as a package with the new changes. If you aren't really trying to simulate a package, importing functions with `source()` will not create a new namespace and would therefore be easier to edit after import.